# OS X El Capitan VoiceOver not reading contents within a scroll

Tags: macos, scrollbar, wai-aria, voiceover

This is my first time with the Mac OS X I want the screen reader i.e., Voice Over to read the contents within the

```
 <div class="scroll" role role="scrollbar" tabindex="-1" title="This is a content">
    This is my content to be read by the Screen Reader
    But its not......................................
    .....................................................
    ................................................................
 </div>
```

But the Voice Over only reads the title for the div after that it reads there is a vertical scroll bar and then the focus moves to the next content and that starts reading. Whereas jaws reads the content for the same div when i tried it on windows.
Anyone faced similar problem or know the solution kindly reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, by removing the [role="scrollbar"] attribute so that the Voice Over for Mac OSX 10.11 now reads the contents inside the scrollbar automatically without having the need of user to press any key.